# How to perform if else operation in angular js depends on which radio button is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two radio buttons in my project. Depending on which radio button is selected I need to send a command to back-end. I tried many ng-**** if else operations which didn't work for me. Kindly help me over the same

---

```js
$scope.compareReference = function() {
  if($scope.radoreslt is checked){
     Factory.send("GetAddonData(CompareBkcXml,$scope.filetxt,File)");
   }else{
  Factory.send("GetAddonData(CompareBkcXml,$scope.filetxt,All)");
   } 
};
```

```html
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false">
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" ng-model="radoreslt" name="r1" checked>Compare with File Specific
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" ng-model="radoreslt" name="r1">Compare All
                </label>
            </div>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="filetxt">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><input type="File"  onchange="copyMe(this)" ></span>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="compareReference()">Compare</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always pass a value attribute to each radio button since the bind model is updated with that value only. Here is an example.

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="radoreslt" name="r1"  value="compareWithSpecific">
<input type="radio" ng-model="radoreslt" name="r1"  value="compareAll">
```

**JS**

```
 $scope.compareReference = function() {
        if ($scope.radoreslt == "compareWithSpecific") {
            Factory.send("GetAddonData(CompareBkcXml,$scope.filetxt,File)");
        } else {
            Factory.send("GetAddonData(CompareBkcXml,$scope.filetxt,All)");
        }
    };
```